# Controller.Endpoint return Ok(responseClass) serializing the ResponseClass erronously

Tags: c#, .net-7.0

Here is my situation.
I have an API project.
Here is a method from its single controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("v1/getStatus")]
    #endregion
    public IActionResult GetStatus(RequestClass request)
    {
         ResponseClass response = _service.GetStatus(request);
         return Ok(response);
    }
```

Here is the ResponseClass:

```
  public class ResponseClass
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the issue:
The final response is purpose-breakingly erronous.

Description:
Take a look at the controlled method (endpoint) in the first code snippet.
Brakpointing the running code at the return line and inspecting the `response` object reveals that all of the data is there.
The final response that is outputted by the API, that is received by for example Postman, HTTPpie, Swagger, is then.. Well weird in a erronour way. Here a direct example:

Actual response (which is correct and whole in the `response` object which is used to `return Ok(response)`):

```
{
   "Code":200,
   "Value":{
      "ResultCode":4,
      "Errors":[
         {
            "ErrorNumber":1,
            "Description":"very bad",
            "DescriptionEN":"much sad"
         },
         {
            "ErrorNumber":1,
            "Description":"good dad",
            "DescriptionEN":"smart head"
         },
         {
            "ErrorNumber":1,
            "Description":"such wow",
            "DescriptionEN":"very amaze"
         }
      ],
      "Exponent":-1,
      "Subtraction":null
   },
   "Name":""
}
```

What `return Ok(response)` yields as the response:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "value": {
        "ResultCode": [],
        "Errors": [
            [
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "Exponent": [],
        "Subtraction": []
    },
    "name": ""
}
```

Do you know what the issue is?
The `Value` property is an `object` because that field is a different type at different points in the process. Is it possible to somehow make it desirializable as, sometimes a string, sometimes the complex object from this example, and etc.?
That would also be somewhat of a solution since I know most (not all) of the types that the `object Value` can be.

---

Edit prompted by Ralf's question below:
[image: Screenshot of the code with an indicitaion that the object used for the Ok response is not erronous, the overal point of which is that the action of return Ok(response) is where the issue occurs.]

The `ResponseClass.Value` type in this case:

```
ResultCode int
Errors List<Error>
Exponent int
Subtraction List<Subtractions>
```

`Error` type:

```
ErrorNumber int
Description string
DescriptionEN string
```

`Subtractions` type:

```
RecordNumber int
Number string
Comment string
```

As regarding the question of which serializer is used. The default .NET 7 one?
All I have in `Program.cs` is                 `builder.Services.AddControllers();`, no options.
This is kinda a hint for what to try next. Will try tomorrow and report back (edit this).

Comment: Can we see the actual type used here for value? And tell us what Serializer is used (Json.Net or System.Text.Json)

Comment: @Ralf hello, I have edited in the answers to your questions.

Comment: @Gandeloft I see that you have a commented line with a `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` call above the Ok call. Does it serializes as intended? I believe that is from the Newtonsoft.Json Package. If you change it to be `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj)`, does it change the serialized json?